# Passing multiple file inputs to razor page as jQuery form data

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, razor-pages

I have multiple form file inputs. The first two file inputs accept single files and the third accepts multiple files. The request does not get forwarded to my action.

On sending the request I'm getting 404 error. What am I doing wrong to pass multiple file inputs? I am new to this stuff so I am not sure what I am missing. Please guide me to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Razor page html:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="file" id="file1" accept=".csv" name="files[0]" class="form-control" />
            <input type="file" id="file2" accept=".txt" name="files[1]" class="form-control" />
            <input type="file" id="fUpload" name="files[2]" accept=".dat" multiple class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top:10px;">
            <input type="button" id="btnUpload" value="Upload" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Razor page Action code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OnPostUpload(List<IFormFile> files)
{

    if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
    {
        string folderName = "Upload";
        string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        string newPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, folderName);
        if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
        }

        foreach (IFormFile item in files)
        {
            if (item.Length > 0)
            {
                string fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(item.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                string fullPath = Path.Combine(newPath, fileName);

                using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    item.CopyTo(stream);
                }
            }
        }

        return this.Content("Success");
    }

    return this.Content("Fail");
}
```

jQuery request:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnUpload').on('click', function () {
        var file1 = $('#file1');
        var file2 = $('#file2');
        var files = $('#fUpload').prop("files");
        var fdata = new FormData();

        fdata.append("files", file1[0].files[0]);
        fdata.append("files", file2[0].files[0]);


        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            fdata.append("files", files[i]);
        }

        if (files.length > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Index?handler=Upload",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                data: fdata,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('File Uploaded Successfully.')
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            alert('Please select a file.')
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: If you're getting a 404 error the problem is because the path you're using inthe AJAX request is incorrect.

Comment: It works fine if I do not append the first two file inputs and pass only the 3rd file input in form data